# Matlab transform 2D matrix to 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix-transform

I have a 2D Matrix `A` like:

```
  A = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6;
    7 8 9 10 11 12;
    1 2 3 4 5 6;
    7 8 9 10 11 12;]
```

I want to transform this 2D Matrix to a 3D Matrix `B` with size 2X3X4, like:

```
B(:,:,1) = [1 2 3; 7 8 9];
B(:,:,2) = [1 2 3; 7 8 9];
B(:,:,3) = [4 5 6; 10 11 12];
B(:,:,4) = [4 5 6; 10 11 12];
```

now what I do is first transform this 2D Matrix `A` to cell type `C` with `mat2cell` and then use `cat` to transform it 3D Matrix `B`, but it is too complicated, since I do not need this cell `C` at all.

Can some give me any advice how I can transform `A` to `B` directly and elegantly?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `A` always 4x6?

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro no, it is just an exmaple, only every page of B is of same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this -

```
[m,n] = size(A);
nr = 2; % Number of rows in o/p
nc = 3; % Number of cols in o/p
out = reshape(permute(reshape(A,nr,m/nr,nc,[]),[1,3,2,4]),nr,nc,[]);
```

Comment: great!!! You have created a 4D Matrix and saved a lot time. But there is a small mistake in your code. I think it should be:

Comment: @JayWang It should be?

Comment: sorry, ctrl + c failed. should be  output = reshape(permute(reshape(A,nr,m/nr,nc,[]),[1,3,2,4]),nr,nc,[])